# Ad Size and Ad unit id must be set before loadAd is called

Tags: java, android, admob

I have this in my main xml file:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="******************"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:id="@+id/adView"/>
```

I have already set the ad size and unit id, but when this is run (from MainActivity.java),

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(com.example.lovetestactual.R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

It threw an exception of what is in the title.

Comment: Can you post your logcat with exception?

Comment: Are you using AdMob from Google Play services?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I found solution in the github example, that is:

instead of

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

delete the xmlns:ads*** tag and add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

tag to your LinearLayout tag as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"/>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's it :)

[github link for this xml](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/banner-xml/res/layout/main.xml)

Comment: how to add AdUnit programatically or without use of xml ?

Answer (score 31):

**Warning:** Make sure you set the ad size and ad unit ID in the same manner (i.e. set both in XML or both programmatically).

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: That was the problem in my case. I had set ID from code, and size from XML.

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be vague as you have not stated what type of view your XML file is (Relative, Linear etc.)

In my application with a scrollable relative layout I have included:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView07"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now inside my actual class that I wan't the ad I have included:

```
private AdView adView;

/* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx/yyyyyy";

/**
 * Simply loads the xml about page layout to display the text.
 */

public void onCreate(Bundle start) {
    super.onCreate(start);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);

    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    //String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            //.addTestDevice(deviceid).build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Now ideally you want to use a smart banner to optimise your layout for all devices, as I have above, this is standard now.

If this is no help head over to [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/)

Comment: Did this help at all?

Answer (score 4):

A lot of people Migrating existing applications to the google play services method are incorrectly adding the wrong information.

Something that I would like to point out is that many people with the same question have been using this as a template

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

This is incorrect as xmlns:ads should be change to:-
    `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Like so

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: You have made my day, literally. Changing the namespace was the thing!

Answer (score 2):

**remove `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` from root view**

then add **AdView**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Remember these steps:

1. You can define `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
    on root view it self .
2. if you have not defined `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` inside rootView then you must need to add `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` inside **AdView.**
3. if you have defined adSize inside your `AdView` xml file then don't set dynamically, like : `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);` or else it will through an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size can only be set once on AdView.`
4. `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` are looking same but there is a difference which is **xmlns:ads** and **xmlns:app** so don't get confuse.

I think it will resolve your issue ... Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

**I faced that same problem because i do not add this line on `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` top of . Then i change my xml code like this**

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/headerText"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    android:visibility="visible">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

*after that i add this 3 line in onCreate method*

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

**you have to replace the xmlns:ads in your parent layout**

```
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

  **by this**
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the namespace declaration but it just doesn't work. I fixed this by specifying a height value for the adView instead of `wrap_content`. It works for me

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested here is a Kotlin version.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</RelativeLayout>
```

And inside the code behind

```
//create a new AdView    
val adView = AdView(this)
adView.adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER
adView.adUnitId = "your adUnitID goes here or you can use a function"
adView.visibility = View.GONE

//add it to the layout
val layout = adContainer
layout.addView(adView)

//profit
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
adView.loadAd(adRequest)
adView.adListener = object : AdListener(){
    override fun onAdLoaded() {
        adView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        super.onAdLoaded()
    }
}
```