# The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd when set programmatically

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

I have no idea what is going on here but I am trying to set my ad unit ID dynamically through code like below and removing it from the XML but still get the error:

> The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(getEvent().getAdMobUnitId());
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: try once by setting ads:adUnitId="UNITID" manually in xml file.

Comment: Not get what you are trying to set add unit Id, you should get it from admob by registering like ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Create it programatically

```
View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.adMobView);

AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);
((RelativeLayout)adContainer).addView(mAdView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And in your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/adMobView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

The best practice for banners, is two show one banner per view (one `unitId`), if you want to show more banners in the same screens (NOT RECOMMENDED), you have to create another `unitId` from [console](https://apps.admob.com) and one adView for each `unitId`.

My answer is:

Don’t know if its a bug or if you can have only one `unitId` per adView and it make more sense, because you can only have one `unitId` per adView, and reading from [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)  they show two ways to do it, by instantianting  a new `AdView()` and programtically setting the `unitIds` and `sizes` OR
do it only from XML.

And I did some tests to arrive at this conclusion.

By using findViewById from your `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`

1 - You can `setAdUnitId` programatically if you set `adSize` first.

2 - You cannot `setAdUnitId`programatically if it’s already in your xml.

3 - If you doesn’t use ’setAdUnitId’ in your xml, it will alert `Required xml attribute adUnitId was missing`, and the same for `adSize` even if you set both attributes programatically.

4 - If not put `setAdUnitId` and `setSize` and put it programtically, the adView will alert you  `Required xml attribute adUnitId was missing`, and the same if you not set `adSize` in xml.

5 - The only thing programatically you can do is call `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)` to load the ad

By using `new AdView()`

1 - It will work if you create an empty layout, then add the adView reference to this view.

2 - You can set the `adSize` and `adUnitId` programatically it will work.

3-  If you try to use `setAdUnitAd` twice this exception will launched `The ad unit ID can only be set once on AdView.` the same if you use by `findViewById`

My conclusions are:

You can use only from XML"

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-my_id_number_was_ommited_by_security" />
```

and load view on onCreate

```
AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

or full programatically

```
View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
AdView mAdView = new AdView(context);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);
adContainer.addView(mAdView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I use banners for a long time and that answer is good for me.

Comment: Yes, you can, and i think my solution is not that you want, so I did a research and I found the `same problem` as yours, please read this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980933/1879661

Comment: I dont see a solution there, except something that has a container, and injects the ad in that.  Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: @MikeFlynn Correct - you reference the container in your Java code and add the AdView to it. When you invoke com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView in XML, that gets instantiated when you call setContentView(some_layout.xml) and makes it easy to configure without Java. As you are doing it dynamically, it gets built and bound. If you want a different adview (size/id) you'll have to create a different one.

Comment: @MorrisonChang the way that i use a container (RelativeLayout) is because I have to use another Banners API in the same container, and then set the banners views programatically if one fails.

Comment: Great explanation, is really important the detail that you cannot declare AdView into xml and set adUnit and adSize programatically!

Answer (score 18):

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This solved my problem.

do not use this

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 4):

add this to your layout

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Even if I write all codes in xml layout, still I got the error. Thanks for reminding me this line.

Answer (score 3):

After trying,

1. Supply adunit ID and adsize from xml ONLY.
2. Supply adunit ID and adsize from .java file ONLY.

Problem is solved by

1. Removing `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` line from root layout.
2. supply adunit ID and adsize as follows,

   `app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
           app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"`

   3. Clean and run app.

Answer (score 1):

You've got

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

From:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#smart_banners

> Note: The smart banner view in your layout must consume the full width of the device. If it doesn't, you'll get a warning with the message "Not enough space to show ad", and the banner will not be displayed.

change it to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

And set your adUnitID in the xml file.

```
ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_ID"
```

Comment: I got that error before, but I fixed it.  This isnt same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_main_screen_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newone);
    initAdsAccount();
    initAds();
}

private void initAdsAccount()
{
    String accountId = AdsConstants.my_fake_ads_account_id;

    if (AdsConstants.isAdsMode)
    {
        accountId = AdsConstants.my_ads_account_id;
    }

    MobileAds.initialize(this, accountId);
}

private void initAds()
{
    findViewById(R.id.ll_main_screen_container).post(//
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    LinearLayout adContainer = findViewById(R.id.ll_main_screen_container);
                    AdView mAdView = new AdView(MainActivity.this);
                    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

                    if (AdsConstants.isAdsMode)
                    {
                        mAdView.setAdUnitId(AdsConstants.main_screen_bottom_banner_id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mAdView.setAdUnitId(AdsConstants.fake_banner_id);
                    }

                    adContainer.addView(mAdView);
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                }
            }//
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was setting the ad type like this:

```
ads:adSize="Banner"
```

While it shall be all caps:

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```