# The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called in android

Tags: android, admob, adview, banner-ads

I am using Adview in my app. But when everytime when I run app got crash and shows following exception. MainActivity.java is first screen after splash screen.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID
>   must be set before loadAd is called.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_category"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

        android:id="@+id/adView_Category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
AdView ad = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView_Category);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();



        ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad failed to load! error code: " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad left application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened();
            }
        });

        ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231810/the-ad-size-and-ad-unit-id-must-be-set-before-loadad-when-set-programmatically).

Comment: i already went through that approach but it dint work properly. why adview not working without any container ?

Comment: @Exigente05 if it is duplicate then post answer without using any container with adview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare AdView like this,

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
```

Or, I guess you need to replace

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

By `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` inside your parent `RelativeLayout`

Comment: right now it is showing error code 0

Comment: That's good. Error code 0 means currently you are not getting ads. This could happen if you request with newly created ID. It will start showing ads automatically after some hours. You have nothing to do but you can test with dummy unit ids - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553929/is-there-any-admob-dummy-id
Hope my answer helps you. :)

Comment: yes right now its not crashing, but can you tell after how many hours it will show my ads. yesterday also it was showing error code 0. ad was not loading

Comment: Here you need to ensure something, adtype (adSize) where you are putting ad unit id should be same of adType you selected while creating ID. There is no exact time, it starts showing after some good request. Have a look these topics - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/fBe3YL3ffpo%5B101-125%5D