# Error while trying to run admob ad on Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, mobile, admob

I am trying to install an admob ad on my webview app that I developed with Android Studio but the app keeps crashing now and I can't seem to get the code right.... everywhere I read about the Android SDK is different information....

This is the error I keep getting and I can't seem to figure out why I am getting it..

```
03-17 02:31:31.637 15034-15034/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file. 
03-17 02:31:31.697 15034-15034/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SGH-I527M_4.4.2_0046                                               
03-17 02:31:31.697 15034-15034/? I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts 
03-17 02:31:31.697 15034-15034/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI 
03-17 02:31:32.127 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 23.093MB for 14791732-byte allocation 
03-17 02:31:32.278 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL                                Build Date: 03/03/14 Mon                                Local Branch: default                                Remote Branch:                                 Local Patches:                                 Reconstruct Branch:  
03-17 02:31:32.428 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0 
03-17 02:31:33.339 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19659: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;)V 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19661: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 19665: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode; 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 545: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 567: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 
03-17 02:31:35.271 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008 
03-17 02:31:35.351 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes V/WebViewChromium: Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {41ea0198} 
03-17 02:31:35.391 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0 
03-17 02:31:35.391 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/BrowserProcessMain: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0 
03-17 02:31:35.521 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL                                Build Date: 03/03/14 Mon                                Local Branch: default                                Remote Branch:                                 Local Patches:                                 Reconstruct Branch:  
03-17 02:31:35.531 15034-15257/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation 
03-17 02:31:35.731 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/Ads: Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing. 
03-17 02:31:35.992 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 
03-17 02:31:35.992 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416cdda0) 
03-17 02:31:36.002 15034-15034/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                    Process: com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes, PID: 15034                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes/com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)                                        
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                        
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                        
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)                                        
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)                                        
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)                                     
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.                                        
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzab.zzdg(Unknown Source)                                        
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzab.zza(Unknown Source)                                        
at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)                                        
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)                                        
at com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)                                        
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)                                        
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)                                         
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)                                         
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)                                         
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                         
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)                                         
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)                                         
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                         
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                         
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)                                         
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)                                         
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
} }
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; 
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd; public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID_HERE";

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://payforlikes.com/");

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




public void displayInterstitial() { // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
} }
```

Here is my content_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
package="com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Instead of xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" delete the xmlns:ads*** tag and add xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto". Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337802/ad-size-and-ad-unit-id-must-be-set-before-loadad-is-called

Comment: that seemed to fix the problem when i did that and added my admob id in the following code:     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"/> </RelativeLayout>

Comment: quick question.... this is only showing a banner ad but i am trying to incorperate a banner ad AND a Interstitial ad...... do you know why the Interstitial ad isnt showing or what i have to add to the code to get it to show?